# VSCode HTML indentation, closing tag on same line

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

When using VSCode indentation on HTML file, tags closing brackets end up at the next line:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I have searched for HTML indentation extension, with no success.
Tnx

Comment: well yeah - what are you expecting? also, a class name that big - is a bad class name

Comment: Turning of word-wrap will help there?

Comment: @treyBake This will happen on any word length.

Comment: @MCMatan it's not about the indentation - class names should, in general never be that long

Comment: @PrashantZombade on all documents? I would not want to change logic on ts files, only html...

Comment: @treyBake This is our convention, big project. And really this question is not about our conventions (: It's about how can I fix VSCode indentation

Comment: @MCMatan personally, I don't see this as broken indentation as it's a common standard and practice to use - PHPStorm also does it by default. It's a normal thing. What are you actually wanting? and why can't manually adding X amount of spaces fix it?

Comment: @treyBake I would like the closing brackets to be at the same line. And again, this is conventions that some people are used too (:

Comment: @MCMatan same line as? and it's the standard - not convention

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> search Word Wrap

```
"editor.wordWrap": "off"
```

May it help you.

Comment: This was my default

Comment: Use this extension : Beautify (ext install HookyQR.beautify)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you may have:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline"
```

Try "`auto`" or another of its options.

Or perhaps you have an extension that does the same as `"force-expand-multiline"`.

Comment: If you have the prettier extension, disable it and see if that is the issue.