# Visual Studio Code - force code formatting to wrap attribute/property withing max line length

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

My question probably sounds familiar and not sure if was added in this shape, but so far I didn't find the solution after over a dozen read questions.

To develop my project I use Visual Studio Code with Angular and Typescript as well as some external libs. There is so many long HTML (and not only) lines in the project, so I would like to have the code well formatted. Let me show the short example:

**before formatting:**

```
<grid-column field="formatCode" title="Format" width="65" class="status-column cell-with-button" *ngIf="width > 1" [class]="{ codeColumn: true }" [hidden]="columns[7].hidden"></grid-column>
```

**expected result:**

```
<grid-column field="incoTermCode" title="Incoterm" width="65"
    class="status-column cell-with-button" *ngIf="width > 1"
    [class]="{ codeColumn: true }" [hidden]="columns[7].hidden"
></grid-column>
```

So expected behavior is to have line wrapped when the max length of the line is exceeded. However I do not want to move each attribute/property to the new line, but keep this line going until again will reach the max length, then move the attribute/property which reached the max line length to another line etc.

So far I was using Prettier code fomratter, but there is no option like I would like to have and [this is in purpose(scroll down for the answers)](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5751#issuecomment-454776010). So this is how Prettier deals with above code example formatting:

**Prettier formatting:**

```
<grid-column
    field="formatCode"
    title="Format"
    width="65"
    class="status-column cell-with-button"
    *ngIf="width > 1"
    [class]="{ codeColumn: true }"
    [hidden]="columns[7].hidden"
></grid-column>
```

This is not I want but let's say it is pretty OK. But look at another example:

**expected:**

```
<div class="valid" *ngIf="form.get('pieces').get([i]).get('quantity').valid>
 <img alt="Validity icon - valid" src="assets/common/images/icons/ValidIcon.svg">
</div>
```

perttier:

```
<div
  class="valid"
  *ngIf="
    form
      .get('pieces')
      .get([i])
      .get('quantity').valid
  "
>
  <img alt="Validity icon - valid" src="assets/common/images/icons/ValidIcon.svg" />
</div>
```

Imagine this is just short example, there are many 3-4 time longer lines in my project which are formatted like that. I really like Prettier, because it does nice job with all this on save fixes, however I do not want to have my files 10+ times more lines than it is necessary.

Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: Does "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline" override the prettier result?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304122/vscode-html-indentation-closing-tag-on-same-line/54306024#54306024.

Comment: Check that. I meant "html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto" of course.

Answer (score 1):

Disable prettier and play around with these settings until you get your desired formatting

```
    "html.format.wrapLineLength": 100,
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "aligned-multiple"
```

Comment: To anyone finding that this may not be working do check that there isn't a custom .vscode/settings.json file in your workspace that is overriding the html.format.wrapLineLength setting.

Answer (score 0):

See if `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto"` will override that prettier formatting.